# Position of Central Maxima due to multiple path differences in YDSE

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, double-slit-experiment, interference

In a YDSE experiment, the apparatus is immersed in a liquid of refractive index $μ_1$. And also one of the slits $(S_2)$ is covered with a transparent slab of refractive index $μ_2$ of thickness $t$ as shown in the figure. I have been asked to find the position of central maxima on the screen.

$(\mu_{3} = 1)$

[image: Figure of the YDSE Apparatus.]

**Attempt at a Solution:**

> The optical path difference at the central maxima must be zero.
>
> $$\delta x = \mu_{1} \frac{y \cdot d}{D} + t(1-\mu_{2}) = 0 \\
> y = \frac{Dt(\mu_{2} -1)}{d \mu_{1}}$$
>
> y = distance of maxima from O
>
> D = distance between the slit and the screen

But my book gives the answer as :

$$y = \frac{Dt(\mu_{2} -1)}{d}$$

I can't find the reason for the missing $\mu{1}$. Please help me find the problem in my approach. Thanks in advance.